# Haskell plotting library similar to MATLAB

Tags: haskell, visualization

Is there a Haskell library for drawing plots similar to MATLAB, scilab or matplotlib? They all have very simple interfaces, which work like a state machine:

```
plot(xs, ys)
show() -- opens window with plot
```

It would be nice to display plots in a window and to have ability to write them to disk.

Comment: I edited your question and replaced "numpy" with "matplotlib", since numpy is not a graphics/plotting library - I assume that you meant matplotlib, but feel free to correct it if I am wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about [gnuplot](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gnuplot)?

For example, `plotList` from `Graphics.Gnuplot.Simple`:

```
plotList [] [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]
```

Comment: I do not like to depent on external applications. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I see that in fact there is nothing better than this. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

From a glance at matplotlib, I don't think the Haskell ecosystem has anything as feature-rich.  However, I've been happy with the results produced by the [Chart](http://dockerz.net/twd/HaskellCharts) library.  There are also bindings to [graphviz](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dotgen) (that links one of several) and [Ubigraph](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hubigraph).

Edit: Responding to the request for plotting (x,y) coordinates:

I'm not entirely clear what you want.  If you have a function `f :: x -> y` then just use the plotWindow (or PNG, etc) function:

```
import Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Simple
main = plotWindow [0,0.1..5::Double] sin
```

If you have a bunch of points, `[(x,y)]`, then the same code with a lookup into the list, instead of a continuous function like `sin`, should work fine.  See the linked page for many many examples.

Comment: Could you give some very simple example of plotting ys against xs? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There is also the `plot` package.  When used with `plot-gtk` graphs can be displayed and modified within GHCi.  Plots can be written to disk in the formats that Cairo supports.

The `Simple` interface is similar to `gnuplot`'s:

```
test_graph2 = do
     plot (ts,[point (ds,es) (Cross,red),line fs blue])
     title "Testing plot package:"
     subtitle "with 1 second of a 15Hz sine wave"
     xlabel "time (s)"
     ylabel "amplitude"
     yrange Linear (-1.25) 1.25
```

Comment: It looks promising, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Try gnuplot. It's cross-language, quite fast at scale, and always a nice thing to know, even if it is old. These instructions should get you a working example:

```
cabal install gnuplot
sudo apt-get install gnuplot-x11

ghci
GHCi, version 7.4.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
h> import Graphics.Gnuplot.Simple
h> plotFunc [] (linearScale 1000 (-20,20)) (\x -> sin x / x)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also [matplotlib-haskell](https://github.com/abarbu/matplotlib-haskell) library (pretty new). It is very expressive yet simple to use.

Example:

```
import Graphics.Matplotlib

plotQuadraticFn :: IO ()
plotQuadraticFn = onscreen $ plot x y
  where
    x = [-10..10]
    y = fmap (**2) x
```