# Is there any ghci GUI frontend/extension that support inline graphics display like ipython?

Tags: user-interface, haskell, ghci

I mean it have features like inline graphics display, worksheet mode, audio playback and ect ... like [ipython](http://ipython.org), maple and matlab

I found [winghci](http://code.google.com/p/winghci) on windows but it doesn't seem to have those features. (BTW, I didn't use Windows)

On Linux, I can't find any GUI mode for ghci. I always run ghci from terminal.

Duplicated? [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868916/haskell-graphics-library-that-works-in-ghci-on-macos-x) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022978/haskell-plotting-library-similiar-to-matlab) show that ghci is capable of do graphics but it is not exactly what I want to know.

Comment: @casperOne I didn't want any comparison here. I want the list of available software, if exists, that I might missed from doing my own search.

Comment: https://github.com/HeinrichApfelmus/hyper-haskell might also apply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Summer of Code project called [GHCLive](http://ghclive.wordpress.com/), which looks exactly like what you want. 
Quite surprisingly, no one is really talking about it.

I wish they were.

Comment: Indeed, good you mention it – I already searched for this upon seeing this question, having read H.Apfelmus' original announcement of the project proposal, but I couldn't seem to find it. — Sure, it doesn't look exactly finished, but _in principle_ works quite nicely.

Answer (score 2):

There's no "graphical" version or variant of GHCi.  As pointed out in the linked questions, there are plenty of Haskell libraries to do [plots, drawings, and other graphics](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pkg-list.html#cat%3agraphics), and there are plenty of libraries that [output audio](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pkg-list.html#cat%3amedia) or [produce music](http://haskell.cs.yale.edu/euterpea-2/).

If you just need nicer Haskell programming helpers, you should look at the various Haskell modes for Emacs (my personal favourite is [ghc-mod](http://www.mew.org/~kazu/proj/ghc-mod/en/)).  These also let you evaluate Haskell expression from Emacs, which could allow you to simulate worksheets.

There are also some pure-Haskell editors like Yi or [Leksah](http://leksah.org/) which do everything the Haskell modes for Emacs do, but in a purer way.  In particular, Leksah aims to be exactly what you're looking for: an IDE for working with Haskell.